# Triggering multiple builds within a build

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a pipeline build for a .NET application called Master Site and then I have three other build definitions using different repos. Every time I have to do a build of the Master site and then the subsequent build. I need to know if we can do multiple builds by triggering a single build request. (all the builds are built off of different repos)

Comment: How is your problem processing?

Comment: I cannot use this extension, is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if we can do multiple builds by triggering a single
>   build request.

For this issue,the answer is yes. You can do this by adding multiple [Trigger Build Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) to the agent job in a build pipeline .

[image]

This tasks allows to trigger a new Build (add it to the queue) as part of a Build Definition.